# Thorntail-Examples / API Incompatibility

Tags: java, maven, thorntail

When trying to package the [thorntail-examples project](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples) on github, the build fails on several of the examples stating an API incompatibility error similar to this...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin:2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT:package (package) on project example-stm: Execution package of goal io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin:2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT:package failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin:2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT:package: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin:2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/<user>/.m2/repository/io/thorntail/thorntail-maven-plugin/2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT/thorntail-maven-plugin-2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/<user>/.m2/repository/io/thorntail/fraction-metadata/2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT/fraction-metadata-2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/<user>/.m2/repository/io/thorntail/meta-spi/2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT/meta-spi-2.3.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/<user>/.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee/2.0.0/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee-2.0.0.jar
...
```

If I remove one of the dependencies, the problem goes away, for example with the [jpa/jpa](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa) example, I receive an API Incompatibility error when I try to build as is, but if I remove the h2 dependency it clears the error.

Having a similar issue with my own project, adding h2 or hibernate results in an API Incompatibility error, but the app runs fine if i leave out both of these.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Sounds weird, I never seen that, and I've been working with `thorntail/thorntail-examples` recently. Is this with Java 8?

Comment: Yes, 8.0.191, running on CentOs 7 with maven 3.6.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thorntail currently doesn't work well with Maven 3.6, as tracked in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-2229. Suggested workaround is to switch back to Maven 3.5 for the time being.

Comment: Wow, I literally searched on those keywords a dozen times and didn't find that.  That is in fact the exact issue, thanks.

Comment: Crazy. My error was "Execution default of goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:7.0.0.redhat-8:package failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:7.0.0.redhat-8:package: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null" while using the WildFly Swarm plugin. So hopefully people will be lead to here when they encounter that error.

Comment: FTR, Maven 3.6 should work just fine with the recently released Thorntail 2.3.0.Final.

Comment: I have this error but I use `Apache Maven 3.5.2`, any idea ?

Comment: Must be a different root cause. Could you ask a new question and provide more details? Thanks.